# Click Button in another application

Tags: c#, api

I'm stucked and I nothing idea what is the problem. I saw another similar topic but not helped me.

here is my code:

```
  foreach (IntPtr se in allchwin)
        {
            IntPtr a = SendMessage(se, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, null);
            StringBuilder outText = new StringBuilder(a.ToInt32() + 1);
            SendMessage(se, WM_GETTEXT, outText.Capacity, outText);

            if (outText.ToString() == "Login")
            {

                SendMessage(se, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, null);
                SendMessage(se, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, null);
                SendMessage(se, BM_CLICK, 0, null);
            }
        }
```

List(IntPtr) -- allchwin: contains the whole child windows handle from the program where to search "Login" button.

I find "Login" button window handle, is this correct value, I checked Spy++ but nothing happens after the command has been sent.
Every SendMessage command return value is 0. The program window is foreground where is the "Login" button. This button has a parent window, is the main window of the program.

I try FindWindow and FindWindowEx, but it has similar results, return value 0.

Any idea why? It is possible to have the program guard click or etc?

Comment: My WinApi knowledge is a bit rusty, but I think you have to get the window handle of the button you want to click, and send the message this very handle. Otherwise, you just "click" the window (not the button).

Comment: Not to trump the question but may I ask why you need to do this?  Myself or another may have a much easier and elegant solution to the problem.  I've found that 100% of the time you need to send messages to any control / windows of your own app your doing it the over engineered and hard way. And @sloth is correct. In WinForms the button has it's own handle.  In WPF things are much different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) API.

Is is COM-based, however there are .net wrappers. Install Windows SDK to get access to API and managed wrappers.

To get button please:

- Find it by handle - see [elementfromhandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/UIAutomationClient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfromhandle).
- Next get `InvokePattern` by calling something like `automationElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern`
- And the last - invoke this pattern: `invokePattern.Invoke();`

Please check also [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation), possible it can help.